how to translate 小林先生が好きだというダンカン?

尊敬する小林先生が好きだというダンカンを、トットちゃんは当然、認めていたし、（見た事がなくても）親しく感じていた。

The phrase "尊敬する小林先生が好きだというダンカン" can be confusing because "が" could be interpreted as either a subject or an object indicator (as in "食べ物がすきだ"). This results in two possible meanings:

Duncan, who likes Mr. Kobayashi.

Duncan, whom Mr. Kobayashi likes.


How should this sentence be translated?


小林先生が好きだというダンカン

Grammatically, this is indeed ambiguous between "Duncan, who likes Mr. Kobayashi" and "Duncan, whom Mr. Kobayashi likes". You need to understand this phrase considering the surrounding context. If ダンカン refers to this well-known celebrity and 小林先生 is a local ordinary person, the latter would be the correct interpretation.
